# Is there any way to make padding from left and right of UILabel? without sub classing of UILabel.

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel

I am looking for a solution that i want to give padding in uilabel but i don't want to subclass of my uilabel. Is there any solution for that. Help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use category class.

Comment: i used it but not able to find solution. could you please show some example.

Comment: can you explain at where you need padding to label ?

Comment: @YunCHEN ya it could be fix but only that  case when it is in single line. my label is in word wrap case and it may contain multiple line also.

Answer (score 0):

You can make padding from left and right of UILabel by initializing your UILabel with a custom frame.

```
CGRect startFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80);
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
CGRect padFrame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(startFrame, contentInsets);
self.yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: padFrame];
```

Comment: label is set in a table view and i set frame in cell.m file by calling a method: 
-(void)setMessageLbl:(NSString*)text withlbl:(UILabel*)lbl{ CGRect startFrame = CGRectMake((imageScrollView.frame.size.width-20)-widthIs, message.frame.origin.y, widthIs+10, 16);
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0,5);
    CGRect padFrame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(startFrame, contentInsets);
    lbl.frame = padFrame;}

Comment: replace last line from self.frame = padFrame  in your cell.m

Comment: but i want to change frame of label by doing self i think it will take cell not cell's label. but i tried like this:  self.lbl.frame = padframe. but still no change.  I used autolayout  so after changing frame i put [lbl setNeedsLayout]; [lbl setNeedsDisplay]; code also.